# BeautifulSoup only returns the first result

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am retrieving data from a website and writing it to a tsv file. However, my code only returns the first set and not the entire set. 
Please Help.

```
BASE_URL = "http://www.parliament.go.ke/index.php/the-national-assembly/house-business/hansard"

#Read base_url into Beautiful soup Object
html = urllib.request.urlopen(BASE_URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

#grab <div class="itemList"> that hold links and dates to all hansard pdfs
hansards = soup.find_all("div","itemList")


#Get all hansards 
#write to a tsv file
with open("hansards.tsv","wt") as f:
    fieldnames = ("date","hansard_url")
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")



    for div in hansards:
        hansard_link = [BASE_URL + div.a["href"]]
        hansard_date = soup.find("h3", "catItemTitle").string

        output.writerow([hansard_date,hansard_link])
        print(hansard_date)
        print(hansard_link)

print ("Done Writing File")
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Wrong DIV. Should have been:

```
#grab <div class="itemList"> that hold links and dates to all hansard pdfs
hansards = soup.find_all("div","itemContainer")
```

And the for loop should be:

```
for div in hansards:
        hansard_link = [BASE_URL + div.a["href"]]
        hansard_date = div.find("h3", "catItemTitle").string
```

Thanks!